# MongoEngine - Query Operator for negation - Substitute for exclude()

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine, negation

I need to make a query with a negation. In Django I would use `exclude()` but regarding to the [MongoEngine doc](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.exclude) exclude means something different.

Is there an query operator or a different function to make a negation?

Example:

```
MyClass.objects.exclude(attribute="test")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you negative operators like ne see http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=ne

Answer (score 5):

You can negate other operators using `not` as an operator prefix:

> `not` – negate a standard check, may be used before other operators (e.g. `Q(age__not__mod=5)`)

(see [MongoEngine's documentation](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=__not__)).

This works in particular for string queries such as

`Post.objects(title__not__contains='Test')`

`exclude` filters attributes on the documents retrieved from the database (see [documentation](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=exclude#retrieving-a-subset-of-fields)).